# How to import JSON data into a bulk cell in SQL from a REST API URL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, rest

I want to download JSON data from a REST API URL directly into SQL Server.

I currently open the URL in a browser and copy the JSON data into a .json file which I save locally, then import using the following code. It would be more efficient if I could just query the URL from SQL server and return the same result.

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\mydata.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;
```

But I want something that replaces the local source with the URL. Eg.

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK (OPENURL("https://restapidata.com/mydata"), SINGLE_CLOB) as j;
```

Result should be a single cell that contains the entire JSON file contents.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the question is?

Comment: "Pure" SQL Server engine can't query URL. You can do it using little .Net code. For example you can write a CLR stored procedure or create a SSIS package.